# Triple bang (!!!) and data frame indexing

Tags: r

I am just learning R, and I am perplexed on why double- and triple-bang (!! and !!!, respectively) sometimes work and other times not. I am thinking I missing some crucial information about their use.

For instance, consider the following example to highlight what I mean:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

df <- read_xlsx("data/elements.xlsx")

cols <- c("rpm", "ferment", "ratio")  # column names
select(df, cols)            # OK
map(df[cols], as.integer)   # OK

cols2 <- syms(c("rpm", "ferment", "ratio"))
select(df, !!!cols2)           # OK
map(df[!!!cols2], as.integer)  # Error in !cols2 : invalid argument type
```

Why doesn't the last line of code work? Any pointers will greatly clear up my confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[` is a `base R` extraction method.  Use the `tidyverse` approaches only with those functions that can evaluate it.

```
map(select(df, !!! cols2), as.integer)
```

---

If we really wanted to use `[`, convert the symbols to character and then use `[`

```
library(rlang)
library(purrr)
cols3 <- map_chr(cols2, as_string)
map(df[cols3], as.integer)
```

Comment: Thank you. You've answered my question and more.